# javascript params object not working

Tags: javascript, .net

In my application I have a javascript function like below.

```
var params = {};
function getMethod(art) {
    if (art == 'artwork') {
        params['type'] = 'paper art';
    }
    params['medium'] = 'canvas';
    params['entity'] = 'paper';
}
```

This function is working fine in Firefox. But Its failing in IE and Chrome.
Its breaking on      params['type']
giving error params is undefined.
Any idea what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: i just tried it on chrome and it works fine, how are you calling the method?

Comment: The posted code is not representative of the code causing the issue. The posted code is fine.

Comment: The posted code was originally missing a single quote after 'paper. The OP modified it without indicating that he had changed it.

Comment: it was a type mistake. it has single quote after paper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how i would use it:

```
var params = {};
function getMethod(art) {
    if (art == 'artwork') {
        params.type = 'paper art';
    }
    params.medium = 'canvas';
    params.entity = 'paper';
}

// ... later
getMethod("not art");

// check if it is defined before using it
if (params.type && params.type == 'artwork') {
   // do artwork stuff
}
```

Comment: params.type, params.medium not working. Its not recognizing. Are you sure we can add new properties like this in Javascript

Comment: yes you can, unless you show how you are calling your function and such there is nothing else i can do